# Mail ID creation

Tags: email

I have a Linux box in which squirrel client installed for mail configuration.
There are 100 employees whose mail id's are running on this.I have grouped 25 employees each to make a group and gave an alias name to send mail to a group.Now they are able to send mail one to one and to a group as well.I want 5 users amongst the group (from any group)who can send mail to a group only.rest of the members can send mail one to one.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

With basic squirrelmail? No. What you want is mailing list software to give you this capability - anyone can send to any address they want to, it is the mailing list software that will determine whether to send the message out to the end recipients based on the sender.

Comment: Yes with basic squirrelmail.Mailing is possible from any user to other.But my concern is i want to restrict some users not to send mail through the alias name in other way i want to allow some users to send mail to a alias name so that it will go to all the members under that group.eg:- group1: user1,user2  group2:  user3,user4 group3:  user5,user6 i want user5 from group3 should not allowed to sent any mail to group1 or group2 where as he should able to send mail to user1,2,3,4,6 one to one.

Comment: Again - if "group1" is a valid destination address, then ANY user in squirrelmail can send mail to it. Period. That's how it works. To restrict the senders int he way you described, you must use mailing list software and set up "group1" as a mailing list with restricted send capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this isn't possible unless you customize the mail clients used by the employees. Still they will be able to sent if they use any other mail client